# Android select currency

Tags: android, format, locale, currency

I saw in the forum that others have the same problem, but no one explains how he solved. 
I have a TextView in my Activity, with a string in currency format

For example, if the user has the phone set to U.S. English language, and yet want to display currency in € or more, how can I do?

```
Double value_tot = Double.valueOf(totale);
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String super_totale = formatter.format(value_tot );
    aTotale.setText(super_totale);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the currency to use in the `NumberFormat` class, like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
nf.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("EUR"));
```

Then `nf.format(123.5)` will produce `"€123.50"`

Comment: then I could make a list of currencies and save the selection in a `SharedPreference`. is the right way?

Comment: Yes, that would seem correct. JFYI, to get the list of all currencies, you can use `Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()`